# What do I have to transmit to get digital audio out of a PCIe lane?

Tags: pcie, digital-audio

I want to get audio out of the PCIe lane and I can't find any chip made solely for this purpose (if you have a suggestion please tell me).

I took it upon myself to design and build it, but I don't know much about it so I don't know how to start. I know that there are 4 data pins for each lane (send +/- & receive +/-) and this is how the card and the CPU communicate, but I don't know if PCIe cards transmit a string of bits and get a string of bits in return. What string of bits do you have to send to get audio back out the `receive data` pins? Is there a handshake of some sort or does a clock have to be sent in order to get the bits at the right time?

Comment: there are different common digital audio formats, eg. 1 bit 2.8 MHz, 16 bit 44 kHz, 24 bit 96 kHz, to name a few. Find a chip with can convert those formats to actual analog audio and read up on their digital input protocol. Search for "audio codec".

Comment: You are more likely to find chips for USB to audio codecs. Then you could use a pcie to usb chip. The other consideration is drivers - choosing a common solution means the drivers are already done for you on most operating systems.

Comment: For low level details of pcie operation, the likes of Mindshare have courses and books on this. Like USB, there are many layers to the protocol, so it is really not something to be explained in a few words.

Comment: Building a PCIe sound card is not simple and you will need to do many orders of magnitude more research before you're ready to design something like that. However, designing a USB sound card is less complex and you can find open source designs on GitHub, articles about designing them, etc. Starting there may be a much better idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have digital audio directly out from a PCIe lane. You need a chip that idetifies itself on the PCIe bus as a sound card, and then the audio is transmitted just as data between the host and the chip.

Comment: i understand that i mean what actual signals do i have to transmit to get that data and then i can relay it as i wish, i just need an analogue signal on the lanes to present on a PCIe card

Comment: You can't have an analogue signal present on the lanes. You can't transmit arbitrary digital signals either. You need an audio chip, and you need to communicate with the protocol that the chip needs to play audio.

Comment: sorry i didnt mean analogue directly out the lanes it was 3am, i meant audio in some format which can then be converted to analogue

Comment: @WilliamBrown But there is no audio on the bus. It can only form a data link with an audio chip and audio is sent as data to the chip which converts it to analog. You basically want a sound card.

Comment: that is what i mean, audio as data in some format, how to get that data ( how to make the data link, what data to send, how to listen for data....) ,not specifically directly as digital audio but in some form which can be deciphered into audio, without a big bulky flashy sound card, just a couple small SMT chips or somet on a PCB using 1 PCIe lane, and getting left and right audio channels and such, maybe more but thats besides the point

Comment: Same way anything else is sent on bus. You need a PCIe chip that is a sound chip. It will form a data link on the bus and operating system knows which sound chip it is to load sound chip drivers which shows up as play and record interface. Then when any program wants to open a sound interface, the driver handles the chip to transfer data which happens to be audio. But that sound chip is still the core device, either integrated on motherboard or on a PCIe card.

Comment: @WilliamBrown The PCIe lane cannot send audio data. It can only send PCIe data. You need a converter chip, which is a sound card. I don't see why it would have to be big, bulky or flashy.